# Are there other ways to encrypt files other then TrueCrypt and BitLocker

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, truecrypt, bitlocker

I don't trust BitLocker. Probably backdoored and relies on TPM which can be hacked according to DEFON. It also does not allow for hidden partitions or other advantages like TrueCrypt.

With TrueCrypt and the state that it is in, are there any other open source options that can be trusted and not backdoored?

Comment: BitLocker doesn't *require* TPM. There is a group policy you can use to work without it. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/

Comment: See [Windows Encrypted Virtual Hard Drive but not Bitlocker or Truecrypt?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4529)

Comment: @Iszi, the problem with that non-TPM method (at least on Win 7) is that it requires you to have the key with you on a USB stick whenever you want to boot up the machine, and that key is not password-protected AFAIK. Hence, it's rather useless overall.

Comment: @Bruno Windows 8 has no such requirement. Password-only mode is perfectly doable. Not sure if that's a limitation in Win7 or not - never really bothered with Bitlocker (preferred TrueCrypt) prior to 8, myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah. There are many alternative to Truecrypt and BitLocker that you can find in link below:
http://alternativeto.net/software/truecrypt/

However I software that meet you prerequisites are **DiskCrypter** and **FreeOTFE**(not supported anymore).
P.S. there is no guarantee that they are backdoor free!