# How robust is a VeraCrypt Container against disk errors (bit rot)?

Tags: integrity, backup, veracrypt, bit-rot

I am planning to encrypt backup data using VeraCrypt. How safe are the generated containers? My worries is not so much the encryption, but potential data loss due to degrading harddisk media (bit rot) over time.

Currently I have an external USB Harddisk, and store each set of backup data twice, in separate folders, A and B. I do a bitwise comparison between A and B from time to time to proove the data integrity.

**I plan to encrypt those backup data folders A and B into separate containers. Here are my questions:**

- Will the created containers still be bitwise comparable?
- How robust will the containers be against data loss, e.g. when a (different) sector in each container fails, will the rest of the data still be
  extractable?
- Can I purposedly have some extra redundancy in the container?
  (I know that this may degrade the encryption somewhat, but as said
  this is not may main concern).

Note: I like to have separate containers against having the whole drive encrypted to be able to handle the backup data sets individually.

Comment: How long are you expecting to store the data for in the same media?

Comment: @LieRyan I am planning for 10 to 15 years on the same media, while doing the comparison about every 6 months or so. Upon replacing the media, the containers will be moved to new media.

Comment: I want to really stress the point I think Lie Ryan is making here. **10-15 years on a single HDD is a really, really long time.** Chances are pretty good that at some point during those years, the drive will fail to spin up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Will the created containers still be bitwise comparable?

No. Veracrypt stores different containers with different encryption keys, even if you use the same password. So the containers won't be bitwise identical. You'll need to open the container and compare the files rather than compare the container.

> How robust will the containers be against data loss, e.g. when a (different) sector in each container fails, will the rest of the data still be extractable?

Veracrypt stores two copies of the volume metadata, one at the front, and one at the end of the volume. Additionally, you can [backup the volume header](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Program%20Menu#tools-backup-volume-header) to make it possible to restore the volume if both embedded metadata is corrupted.

[Veracrypt encrypts in XTS mode](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cascades), which means that [data corruption in one block only affects that block](http://www.kingston.com/en/usb/encrypted_security/xts_encryption).

However, you should consider that modern hard disk are very good at detecting and self correcting for errors. They do this by encoding the data in such a way that there are redundant information to allow the hard disk to recompute corrupted bits, the general technique is called [error correcting code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction).

In addition, if you use a modern filesystem in your host system, like btrfs or zfs, [modern filesystem adds additional checksums](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/bitrot-and-atomic-cows-inside-next-gen-filesystems/) to automatically detect errors and they can also be configured on RAID configuration so they can automatically make redundant copy when storing files so they can automatically repair errors to protect against media degradation. Due to their design, it's nearly impossible that you'll get silent corrupted data due to media degradation with modern filesystem.

The only practical failure scenario for modern filesystem is bugs in the filesystem implementation and user errors. You have a much better likelihood of accidentally `rm -f container.tc`-ing your data. And for a catastrophic physical disk failure where the entire hard disk just stopped working, in which a backup on the same device would not be able to help you. To protect against these, you would want to make a backup copy of your data on multiple devices and migrate to a new storage media probably once every 5-7 years.

Answer (score 0):

I use free ExactFile to calculate and store a hash value for each file stored on backup media.  I use Samsung FIT+ mini flash drives. I do not use hard disk drives any more.

Then, I can run a file verification operation periodically to check data integrity. This is known as an active archive.

Instead of comparing two copies of the same file, bit for bit, you compare the current computed hash value with the stored expected hash value, which is much quicker.

I keep multiple copies of backup files on separate flash drives and on Proton Drive encrypted cloud storage.

Comment: ExactFile is end-of-life and no longer being maintained - also, as far as i'm aware it doesn't sign the digests of the files, which leaves them open to subsequent interference .. i recommend switching to `openssl.exe` or `certutil.exe` for producing digests, and `ssh-keygen.exe` for signing the digest-files ; these are available in [`git`](https://git-scm.com/download/win) for windows - also [Portable-git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) - start `git-bash.exe` and from there you can use these programs against your filesystem

Comment: Yes, ExactFile is old software, but it is a free hash generator/checker that works fine for my personal/small business needs. I don't need signed hash values.

Comment: Files stored in a VeraCrypt container are protected from tampering.

Robust archiving software should also keep a directory file count, to detect added or deleted files, known as fixity.  There is software named Fixity that was once free software, but is now paid software.

Acronis True Image backup software includes stored blockchain hash values and a scheduling periodic data check feature.

Comment: in what way does veracrypt protect files at rest from being tampered with? my understanding is you would need a separate mechanism to make this guarantee - either on the individual files themselves, or on the container file as a whole (or both)

Comment: actually, we're debating a side issue anyway - nothing in this answer contributes to recovering from bit-rot or corruption - what is really needed is [some form of forward-error correction](https://github.com/tahoe-lafs/zfec) applied to the data at rest in the veracrypt container (i managed to get zfec working in py3 without too much trouble- it's probably off topic here)

Comment: Store backup copy 1 and hash values in container 1 on drive 1.
Store backup copy 2 and hash values in container 2 on drive 2.
Use strong random password with 100 bits of entropy.
Periodically, verify file integrity using hash checker utility.
IF hash compare error (due to bit rot, end of life, defect, EMP), THEN replace defective file with known good copy from another backup copy with correct hash value.
I keep at least 3 copies of important files in local and remote encrypted cloud storage.
I keep at least one backup copy in a fireproof waterproof digital media safe.

Comment: re-reading and you actually did say that you keep multiple copies: please accept my apologies- it was incorrect of me to state that your answer didn't address this